# Proper configuration for: synth pedal + expression pedal + amp

Tags: electric-guitar, equipment, setup

Had some great input from this electric guitar question: [What type(s) of equipment is needed for real-time distortion / tone modulation on an electric guitar?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/116773/what-types-of-equipment-is-needed-for-real-time-distortion-tone-modulation-o)

As a quick recap:

- Goal: To be able to go from built-in amp tones to crazy glitch-tune tones
  at will
- Solution: Until I reach John-5 status, I think I'll settle for a synth pedal to achieve glitch-tune tones

Since I asked that question, I have got an amp and now I'm finally starting to assemble the rest of the hardware (synth pedal + expression pedal).

The only remaining stumbling blocks I imagine I'll run into is how to properly set up my equipment:

- Roland EV-5 expression pedal
- Yamaha THR10II amp
- Boss SY-1 synth pedal

**Note:** I have no idea as to whether this is an ideal set up or not, but I've already committed to it; they are on the way. Ideally, it would have been nice to go to a music shop where I can actually talk to experts, but due to current circumstances of my area, had to order online. I tried to pick the vendor's brain before I pulled the trigger but he didn't know if it would work or not. I also tried ask my friend who is a real wizard with guitars but he said he didn't know either (he plays well, but not too familiar with hardware stuff).

### Question

What cables need to go where for these three pieces of hardware to interface correctly to allow me to switch from native amp tones to synth tones at will?

(don't need a fancy diagram or anything, maybe some text arrows about synth in/out and amp in/out and where the expression pedal should go.)

**Edit** Just for clarity, the desired result of this setup is to press down on the expression pedal to toggle the SY-1 and release to go back to normal amp tones (in mid-song).

Comment: Side note, you can get very glitchy with the right kind of fuzz pedal - like a Zvex Fuzz Factory. It doesn’t have to be a synth pedal at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need a power supply for the SY-1, either from BOSS or compatible  (9V, stabilized, negative pin in the middle). Batteries wouldn't last long.
2. EV-5 seems to come together with a connection cable, to be plugged into SY-1.
3. Connect guitar to input of SY-1 with a regular guitar cable (mono 1/4"), and output of SY-1 with another guitar cable to input THR10II.

Comment: Good to know about the power supply, will look into that. Is the expression pedal needed, not sure if SY-1 has expression built-in or not?

Comment: Actually, if I have my amp plugged into the wall, is there a way to feed the power from the amp to the synth pedal? Or do I need a standalone power supply for the synth pedal?

Comment: @arashhowaida you'll need or an extension cord with several out socket to connect the pedal from the wall, alongside the amp with its own supply. Note that it can also be supply with some special "battery pack" made for that purpose. I would be surprised if the amp could feed some power to the pedal

Comment: @Tom Hmmm, makes me wonder, if I'm just playing in my living room, could I just use DC (wall power) cables, one for amp and another for synth pedal?

Comment: @arashhowaida This is not a good idea, even if it worked: pedals sound is usually very dependent on the quality of power supplied by the power supply. The amp, with is drawing quite a bit more current than the pedal will probably pollute the power line and interfere with the pedal. It's not for nothing that isolated and stabilised pedal power supply exist!

Comment: The power for SY-1 is 9VDC. Doubtful you have that small amount in a wall socket - you sure it's DC? Batt. will last ~3hrs. Do not leave jacks plugged in when not in use. There's a socket for EV-5 on the SY-1. Always good to read instructions (on line) before spending money!

Comment: Seems like the Yam. uses 15VDC, so a separate wall wart is needed for it.

Comment: @ArashHowaida you need a 9V stabilized power supply with negative pin in the middle. As Tim pointed out, Yamaha uses 15V, that's too much for BOSS.

Comment: @ArashHowaida BOSS SY-1 doesn't require expression pedal to use, and it is not included. Expression pedal is used to activate additional functions. Make sure you read SY-1 manual and listen to demonstrations or sound samples to learn if and how it may allow you to get the sounds you want.

Comment: @user1079505 I looked at some demos online and heard a lot of the sounds it can produce but didn't find anything on the wiring/setup. I was under the impression that an expression pedal would be needed to switch between the synth pedal and amp tone. I.e. pressing down on the expression pedal when I want glitch and releasing when I don't (in mid-song).

Comment: @ArashHowaida SY-1 is called a "pedal" for a reason. You step on the bottom part to activate and deactivate the effect. You can attach an expression pedal or a footswitch to modify the effect parameters in real time. Go to BOSS page, download and read the manual of SY-1. It describes all the functions, and also includes connection diagrams. By the way, perhaps reading the manual of the amp might be also useful to decide if it has functions you need.

Comment: @user1079505 Understood. Then, on your actual answer, you mention in part 4: about the output of the amp. But I guess nothing goes into the out of the amp right? We just go [first cable] guitar->SY-1(IN) | [second cable] SY-1(OUT)->amp(IN)?

Comment: @ArashHowaida Ah, you're right! I realize I misunderstood you. I thought you spoke about connecting amp to an [audio] interface (noun), but now I see you ask about interfacing (verb) various parts of the equipment. Corrected the answer.