# How to use an expression pedal with Yamaha THR10 II?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers, equipment

The Yamaha THR10 II has a USB port on the back but doesn't have RCA in/out ports on the backs like other models seem to have. I have tried to search some forums about how the set up is supposed to work for the THR10 II.

The only thing I saw that might work is using a 1/4" to 1/8" adapter so that my expression pedal (a 1/4" gauge cord) can plug into the the THR10 II's aux port. But I'm not sure if that is where it should go. Unfortunately the THR instruction manual didn't cover this and the pedal manual only included directions for hooking up to a keyboard.

I have a feeling it's really simple, but I'm really new and just worried I'll mess something up.

### Question

How should I go about wiring an expression pedal to my THR10 II amp?

**Context:** What I hope to achieve is:

- Set amp dials for overdrive tone
- Press down on expression pedal to quickly go back to clean when I
  don't want overdrive

Comment: Most likely do that with an app.

Comment: The manual for the amp at https://uk.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/7/1287107/thr30ii_en_rm_b0.pdf mentions being able to control the amp with an app - 'THR 
Remote' - and the web page for that app at https://uk.yamaha.com/en/products/musical_instruments/guitars_basses/amps_accessories/thrremote/index.html mentions footswitch support. If what you want to do is quickly change amp settings, have you explored that route?

Comment: Most guitarists will use the volume control on the guitar to vary the amount of overdrive. Try that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of expression pedal?
Does it have one socket in & another socket out, or does it have a single cable with a plug on the end? Pictures or make & model would help.

The way you're asking makes me think it is the second type.
This is not compatible with any guitar amp unless it has a specific socket for that function. The two systems are simply not compatible, & such a pedal would normally be used on a keyboard, with a processor to handle it.

A guitar volume pedal is a simple attenuator; guitar signal in, attenuation, signal out - to regular guitar input.

Compare - Yamaha single-cable expression pedal, for keyboards & 'smart' controllers. [Yamaha FC7 Heavy Duty Expression Pedal /Volume Pedal](https://www.yamahamusiclondon.com/FC7-Heavy-Duty-Expression-Pedal--Volume-Pedal/pidCFC7)

Guitar  volume & expression pedals - [Volume & Expression Pedals](https://www.andertons.co.uk/guitar-dept/guitar-pedals/volume-expression-pedals?#facet:&productBeginIndex:0&facetLimit:&orderBy:&pageView:grid&minPrice:&maxPrice:&pageSize:&) - read the FAQs at the bottom of the page & the explanation linked as to the difference between simple volume & expression - https://www.andertons.co.uk/guitar-expression-volume-pedal-guide

Comment: it's the roland E5 model expression pedal

Comment: You mean [E**V**5](https://www.roland.com/uk/products/ev-5/)? This is a keyboard controller, not a guitar expression. btw, the E5 is a keyboard.

Comment: oh golly, good thing I asked. Guess I'll return it. From what I now understand, something like the Boss FV 500-H is actually what I want for an expression pedal.

Comment: Yup. Looks more like the type you want.

Comment: @ArashHowaida the Boss FV 500-H is not an expression pedal, it's a simple volume pedal. If you want something to go clean by simply attenuating your signal, it might be useful. If you want to change your amp settings, I don't see how it will be useful...?

Answer (score 3):

Plug a pedal into aux? That's more likely an input for a player of some kind - CD, etc.

Use the app to change settings and there'll be one to 'change channels'. Probably needs changing by hand rather than foot, though.

What you have (EV-5) is what I use solely for keyboards - it won't change volume wherever you plug it in that amp. FV-50 - L/H is a volme control pedal, which you plug guitar in input and out goes to amp in. But that's not going to change channels, only attenuate the guitar volume - which is usually done using the pot on the guitar. When on overdrive, it tends to change the amount of distortion rather than the volume, though.

Answer (score 3):

- The AUX input in THR10ii is used for an additional audio source, e.g. backing tracks. You cannot control the app by connecting an expression pedal or a footswitch to that input.
- I found that Xsonic company makes bluetooth footswitches for THR series amps. The most expensive version of the footswitch also has an input for an expression pedal. I never used this equipment and have no opinion about it.
- THR series are small amps made primarily for practice. When you practice at home you can change the sounds by manipulating the amp settings with your hands. Footswitches are needed primarily for performing in front of the audience. Consider if the equipment you want to buy is what you actually want.
- In general expression pedals are used when you want to smoothly blend between two sounds, or adjust a parameter in real time. If all you want is to *switch* between two sounds, a footswitch is typically sufficient.
- This is another question, after this [Proper configuration for: synth pedal + expression pedal + amp](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/119059/proper-configuration-for-synth-pedal-expression-pedal-amp) in which you ask about very basics of the equipment. In the other question you ask about buying an external effect pedal for the practice amp. An effect pedal can be turned on and off, so it allows to switch between two sounds. A solution for you could buy to an external overdrive/distortion pedal, although I'm not sure if it would cost effective.

Answer (score 0):

I will add for anyone in the future. There are some products on the market that converts the type of pedal you have, a MIDI expression meant for controllers and keyboards, to USB. From there you can use these types of pedals to control parameters in a DAW, so it works as an expression pedal, at least for direct in recording. They are quite expensive though, even more so than many cheaper pedals... I haven't tried it but am about to order one, and I heard good things about this one specifically: https://beatbars.com/en/expression-to-midi.html

There are a couple others on the market as well, but they aren't very common and relatively expensive.